# Tableau Data Engine Error 4

Tags: tableau-api, character-limit

I'm trying to connect to a csv file locally on my computer, and I'm getting the following error message:

[image]

From previous experiences I've found out that, at least when connecting to xls/xlsx files, I get the "Error: 4: error generating sort key", when any string in my data set has a length of more than 255 characters.
For this one however, the longest strings are 251 (I'm creating my dataset in R, and have a good overview and instant control of all string's lengths).

I've tried to minimize the length of all strings to 225 characters, and... it works. But, I want to maintain as much string length as possible plus I've never heard before that the limit should be lower than 255. Then I tried pushing it to 245 characters, and actually that worked too - i.e., it worked the first time around - second time I got the same error as before. Some times I get another error message instead, saying simply "String Comparison Error". I'm really confused about what's causing this. Starting to think it might not be entirely dependent on the string character length, but that there's something else to it as well.

What else could cause this error?

EDIT: I'm using Tableau 9.2.0 64 bit version

Comment: Which version of Tableau are you using ?

Comment: Hey. It's Tableau 9.2.0 64 bit

Comment: Also, I should mention that I have another identically structured text file with string lengths up towards 300 chars, that reads in Tableau with no problems at all.

Comment: I am using 9.2 version and I am not facing any issue in this ......... also allowed more than 255 character in excel ...... you will check your odbc setting may be there should be some issue in that.

Comment: I suggest install driver again may be resolve your issue........

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but I had the same issue, and like you I'm Danish (connection there).

My problem happens when one of my LT collegaues makes changes in the workbook, the only way to solve it is to change my regional settings to anything using . as decimal seperator and , as thousand seperator (ie. English UK).

Strange thing, once I've done it, I can change back, and keep using it on danish, but once I've restarted, same issue again.

In 9.3 is was Error generating sort key

In 10.2 it's string comparison error

Annoying error, that I really should report in detail, so they can fix it.